# How to set up rewriting of URLs in website residing inner folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, iis-8.5

how can I map the default document file from folder. There I have a index.html file.

```
sitename.com —> root/folder1
sitename.com/url1 —> root/folder2
sitename.com/url2 —> root/folder3
```

While I configure as

```
<rule name="rootFolder1" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^.*$" />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="/folder1/{R:0}" />
</rule>

<rule name="rootfolder2" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^url1.*$" />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="/folder2/" />
</rule>

<rule name="rootfolder3" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^url2.*$" />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="/folder3/" />
</rule>
```

The js file and css files are not working with this folder2 and folder3. They are taken from folder1. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: The first rule is catch-all, so you cannot put it at top. Cut and paste the last two rules to the top please. However, you might also need to improve those two rules (learn regular expression, add capture group, and use `{R:1}`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decision my question

```
 <rule name="rootfolder2" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="url1(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/folder2/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="rootfolder3" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="url2(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/folder3/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="rootfolder1" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^.*$" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/folder1/{R:0}" />
```

Thanks [lex-li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11182/lex-li)!